# Multiple Channels with Different Service Paths

Tags: java, websocket, netty

**[I am using Netty-Websokcet]**

I have a use case where different service paths should be connected to the same port. I tried so many different ways, reasons I couldn't get the work done was,

- In `ServerBootstrap` class there is only one place for `ChannelHandler` therefore I cannot add multiple child handlers in `ServerBootstrap` with different service paths
- In `ServerBootstrap` class it is not possible to create multiple groups

This is how my init channel looks like,

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
    logger.debug(1, "Initializing the SocketChannel : {}", socketChannel.id());

    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(
            new HttpRequestDecoder(),
            new HttpObjectAggregator(maxPayloadSize),
            new HttpResponseEncoder(),
            new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, listenerConfig.getSocketTimeout(),
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS),
            new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler(ingressConfig.getURI().getPath()), // (A)
            new WebSocketServerCompressionHandler(),
            new WebSocketIO(listenerConfig, manager), // a handler
            new WebSocketMessageListener(messageReceiver, manager) // a handler
    );

    logger.debug(2, "Successfully initialized the Socket Channel : {}", socketChannel.id());
}
```

This code line **(A)** registers a handler with the given service path (service path is `ingressConfig.getURI().getPath()`)

```
 int maxPayloadSize = listenerConfig.getMaxPayloadSize();
    try {
        bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(listenerConfig.getBossThreadCount());
        workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(listenerConfig.getWorkerThreadCount());

        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .childHandler(new WebSocketListenerInitializer(messageReceiver, maxPayloadSize, listenerConfig,
                        ingressConfig))
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.bind(port);
        channelFuture.sync();
        channel = channelFuture.channel();

        if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
            logger.info(1, "WebSocket listener started on port : {} successfully", port);
        } else {
            logger.error(2, "Failed to start WebSocket server on port : {}", port,
                    channelFuture.cause());
            throw new TransportException("Failed to start WebSocket server", channelFuture.cause());
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        logger.error(1, "Interrupted Exception from : {}", WebSocketListener.class);
        throw new TransportException("Interrupted Exception", ex);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me a way how to do this?